# Data doesn't appear in ASPxPopupControl

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I want my popup to display user data (possibly with edit/delete options). I've handle following function to the RowDBclick:

```
popupControl.Show(grid.GetSelectedKeysOnPage());
```

And in the popupControl I've set Popup Element Id to grid which is my ClientInstanceName of the GridView. The popup appears but with no data. What do I do wrong? How to display user data of the clicked row id? If I set Choose data source in Popup task panel to my db ConnectionString, the popup doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

There is no client-side Show method for ASPxPopupControl that accepts an array of values. [ASPxClientPopupControlBase.Show Method](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebScriptsASPxClientPopupControlBase_Showtopic). You need to perform a callback on the PopupControl ([PerformCallback](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebScriptsASPxClientPopupControlBase_PerformCallbacktopic)), populate its controls with required values obtained from the grid in the server-side [WindowCallback](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxPopupControlBase_WindowCallbacktopic) event handler. After this show the popup.